# Error from python worker:... SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, pyspark

I just installed Python, Spark, Hadoop with Eclipse on MAC OSX through this website : "https://enahwe.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-developing-with-python-and-spark-on-hadoop/". I am on step 8 of this installation guide.
When I am running the MyWordounts file I get this error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/09/15 12:12:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/09/15 12:12:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Error from python worker:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 177
  file=sys.stderr)
      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PYTHONPATH was:
  /Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/MyPythonSparkProject:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:395)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/09/15 12:12:27 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Error from python worker:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 177
  file=sys.stderr)
      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PYTHONPATH was:
  /Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/MyPythonSparkProject:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:395)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/09/15 12:12:27 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Phoenix/Documents/MyPythonSparkProject/src/MyWordCounts.py", line 26, in <module>
for wc in wordCounts.collect(): 
  File "/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Error from python worker:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 177
  file=sys.stderr)
      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PYTHONPATH was:
  /Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/MyPythonSparkProject:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:395)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Error from python worker:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 177
  file=sys.stderr)
      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PYTHONPATH was:
  /Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/MyPythonSparkProject:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python:/Users/Phoenix/Documents/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:395)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
... 1 more

17/09/15 12:12:27 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
```

Here is a picture of my PYTHONPATH used for the specific project:[looks like python 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdM3k.jpg)

Do you have any idea of how i can solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Your PYTHONPATH suggests you are running Python 2.7, not Python 3.6. You can't run Python 3 syntax with Python 2.

Comment: I am not sure to see where you see i am using Python 2.7. Is it because i  am using Hadoop 2.7?

Comment: It is definitely *not Python 3*, because that specific module is otherwise perfectly valid Python 3 code. But if run under Python 2, you'd get that exact syntax error.

Comment: You were right, but the problem wasn't from PYTHONPATH environnement variable. In my Python Interpreter I added PYSPARK_PYTHON environnement variable with the value of my python 3.6 full path so the Sark driver use the right version of python. Thank you a lot Martijn!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with version 3.7, I solved it by adding the following to the Environment section (Eclipse -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python interpreter -> Environment):

PYSPARK_PYTHON /usr/local/bin/python3.7
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON python3

[image: Eclipse PyDev preferences]